# How to solve this task about circles and lines intercepting each other?

Tags: geometry, circles

We have drawn some lines and circles on a paper. Every two has an interception, but none three goes through the same point. How many lines and circles have we drawn if we have 75 interceptions?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Also, please try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: The tag ([tag:algebraic-geometry]) is intended for questions in a branch of mathematics called algebraic geometry (see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebraic-geometry/info).) The tags ([tag:algebra-precalculus]) and/or ([tag:geometry]) should be used for basic problems that involve both algebra and geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have $m$ lines and $n$ circles. Any pair of lines has exactly one intersection. I assume that any pair of circles as well as any combination of one line and one circle has *two* intersections, since otherwise this question would be impossible to answer. So you have in total

$$\binom{m}{2} + 2mn + 2\binom{n}{2}$$

points of intersection. Since $\binom{13}{2}=78>75$ you can be sure that $m,n<13$. Simple trial and error will show you that in the range $0\le m,n<13$ there is only one pair satisfying the number of intersections given in your problem statement. If you don't want to (let a computer) compute all counts for all pairs in that range, you can start with $n=12,m=0$. Whenever the count is too low, increase $m$. Whenever it is too high, decrease $n$. Do so until you have found your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and fast answer.